# Undefined index: label vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Select.php on line 68

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, third-party-module, system-config

I'm getting this error when going to a custom extension's (IWD_Opc) admin configuration page.

```
Undefined index: label in .../vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Select.php on line 68
```

Any ideas what this error means or how to go about fixing it?

Using Magento 2.2.2.

This seems to be connected with `/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` with one of the fields, still not sure which one or why this is happening...

**EDIT**

It's connected with a new custom payment method and the system config field:

```
<field id="default_payment_method" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Default Payment Method</label>
      <source_model>IWD\Opc\Model\Config\Source\Payment</source_model>
</field>
```

Model code is:

```
use Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods;

class Payment extends Allmethods
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = parent::toOptionArray();
        array_unshift($options, ['value' => '', 'label' => '-- Please select a payment method --']);
        return $options;
    }
}
```

So I presume that my custom payment method is not registered properly to be included in the `Allmethods` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was just a typo in my custom payment method's `/etc/config.xml`

```
<group>Offline</group>
```

Should be

```
<group>offline</group>
```

Comment: the capital letter was the issue?

Comment: @jibingeorge Yes. It seems it is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @Lez, You saved my day. !